# fatal error em mysql_select_db( )

Tags: php

Sou novato em `PHP` e atualmente estou estudando `PDO`, fiz uma estrutura simples e está com um erro que não consigo identificar. Já vi vários exemplos de pessoas usando a mesma estrutura e funciona.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "test";

$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);
$db = mysql_select_db($conexao, $dbname);

$nome = "exemplo";

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios_teste WHERE nome = $nome  ");
?>
```

Os erros que recebo são:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db()
>
> Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db()

Comment: As funções `mysql_` não existem mais no php7, deve usar as mysql**i**_

Comment: tentei achar algo parecido como "mysqli_select_db" no manual do php e não encontrei, achei que essa função em especifico não tinham alterado, obrigado

Comment: Se está estudando PDO aconselho a dar uma olhada nisso: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

A função `mysql_select_db()` foi removida a partir da versão 7.0.0, [conforme aviso na própria documentacao](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php):

> Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_select_db() PDO::__construct() (part of dsn)

Se você está utilizando uma versão mais nova, vai se deparar com este problema.
Uma solução é utilizar sua substituta `mysqli_select_db` (repare no "i"):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");

mysqli_select_db ( $con, $dbname );
```

Mais detalhes: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: procurei algo parecido com "mysqli_select_db" no manual e não encontrei, achei que esta função em especifico não tinham alterado, obrigado!

Comment: Mesmo que o autor use uma versão do PHP que tenha a função, ela não vai funcionar com MySQLI - De curiosidade, o DB pode ser passado direto na hora da conexão, se quiser eliminar a linha do select_db inteiramente da jogada